# CAKE-PHP how to save dynamic array in the MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

i am creating a dynamic array and saving into the table here is my saving model

Model:
i have CATEGORIES and CATEGORIES have many PRODUCTS and then PRODUCTS have many SUB PRODUCTS and SUB PRODUCTS may have many OPTIONS

Here is VIEW code through which i am creating dynamic check boxes

```
<tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f3f5f6;">
                  <?php // debug($Product);exit; ?>  

                <?php

                    //foreach ($Product as $Products):  ?>  
                    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('Artdetail.products.', array('value'=>$Product['Product']['id'],'hiddenField'=>false)); ?>
                        <?php echo $Product['Product']['product_name'].'<br/>' ?>

                    <?php 

                    foreach ($Product['SubProduct'] as $subproducts):?>

                   <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('Artdetail.products.'.$Product['Product']['id'].'.subproducts.', array('value'=>$subproducts['id'],'hiddenField'=>false)); ?>
                        <?php echo $subproducts['subproduct_name'].'<br/>' ?>




                    <?php 

                    foreach ($subproducts['Option'] as $options):  ?>


                    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('Artdetail.products.'.$Product['Product']['id'].'.subproducts.'.$subproducts['id'].'.options.', array('value'=>$options['id'],'hiddenField'=>false)); ?>
                        <?php echo $options['optname'].'<br/>' ?>

                            <?php 

                            endforeach;?>

                    <?php 

                    endforeach; ?>

               <?php  endforeach;?>
               </td>
            </tr>
```

and here is my CONTROLLER code

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                    $this->Artproject->create();


            $this->request->data['Artproject']['ainum'] = 'AI-' . $this->request->data['Artproject']['ainum'];
            $this->request->data['Artproject']['createdby'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

            if ($this->Artproject->save($this->request->data['Artproject'])) {
                  $artid = $this->Artproject->getLastInsertID();

               foreach ($this->request->data['Artdetail']['products'][$prdid]['subproducts'] as $subproducts):

                  //debug($subproducts);

                 $this->request->data['Artdetaill']['category_id'] = $sportid;
                 $this->request->data['Artdetaill']['product_id'] = $prdid;
                 $this->request->data['Artdetaill']['subproduct_id'] = $subproducts;
                  $this->request->data['Artdetaill']['user_id'] = $this->request->data['Artproject']['user_id'];
                 $this->request->data['Artdetaill']['art_id'] = $artid;

                 if(!empty($subproducts['options'])){

                 foreach ($subproducts['options'] as $options):

                $this->request->data['Artdetaill']['option_id'] = $options;
                 $this->Artdetail->saveAll($this->request->data['Artdetaill']);  
                 endforeach;

                 }else{

                      $this->Artdetail->saveAll($this->request->data['Artdetaill']);  
                 }


                 endforeach; 
           exit;
            }

        }
```

after submit i get this array

```
array(
    'Artproject' => array(
        'ainum' => '1024',
        'teamname' => 'Basketball',
        'user_id' => '10',
        'createdby' => ''
    ),
    'Artdetail' => array(
        'products' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => array(
                'subproducts' => array(
                    (int) 0 => '1',
                    (int) 1 => array(
                        'options' => array(
                            (int) 0 => '1',
                            (int) 1 => '2'
                        )
                    ),
                    (int) 2 => '2',
                    (int) 3 => '3'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

and i want to save it in the art details table 
id
user_id
art_id 
category_id
product_id
subproduct_id
option_id
created

![This is my form through which i am submiting 
[Click Here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chMdu.png)

Comment: Are those the ArtDetails field names at the bottom of the screen? If so, you should name your form fields the same as the model field's to make the `save` work . Also, based on your relationship structure, if your ArtDetail can only have 1 option_id, then you don't need to save the subproduct_id, nor the product_id.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store data by serializing array?
Simply serialize($yourarr); and store with a unique key you want to identify your array

Comment: thank for the reply its saving in table but when i select options its creating mess and does not save options in the option_id column

Comment: Take two columns one as option_id which is primary and auto increment. and second as data with datatype text and store serialized data in text column. But I will suggest to use primary key as some value which make you traverse easily forexample: ainum and product id composite key

Comment: I wouldn't save it as an serialized array....you cannot really search in the database for your values anymore. or at least it is a pain in the a**e.
Rather learn how cakephp really works

Comment: yes @conehead we cannot then search in table for values

Answer (score 0):

Wow....way too much code.

```
array(
    'Artproject' => array(
        'ainum' => '1024',
        ...
        'Artdetail' => array(...)
    ),    
)
```

Put your Artdetail object within your Artproject.
Then you only need this code in your controller:

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Artproject->create();
        $this->request->data['Artproject']['ainum'] = 'AI-' . $this->request->data['Artproject']['ainum'];
        $this->request->data['Artproject']['createdby'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Artproject->saveAssociated($this->request->data['Artproject'], array('deep' => true))) { }

    }
```

Just make sure your model-associations are correct.

Comment: thanks for reply can you please tell me about association that what would be my model association

Comment: array(
 'ainum' => 'AI-1024',
 'teamname' => 'Basketball',
 'user_id' => '10',
 'Artdetail' => array(
  'products' => array(
   (int) 0 => '1',
   (int) 1 => array(
    'subproducts' => array(
     (int) 0 => '1',
     (int) 1 => array(
      'options' => array(
       (int) 0 => '1',
       (int) 1 => '2'
      )
     ),
     (int) 2 => '2',
     (int) 3 => '3'
    )
   )
  )
 ),
 'createdby' => '7'

NOW this is my array after Puting the Artdetail object within my Artproject.

Comment: show some code of your models please.

Guess you need something like:

Product HABTM Categories
Product HABTM Products (Subproducts)
Product HABTM Options.

well...depending on what you would like to have. It might be just an belongsTo or hasMany relation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ARTDETAIL MODEL:  
public $belongsTo = array(
            'User' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            ),
            'Artproject' => array(
                'className' => 'Artproject',
                'foreignKey' => 'artproject_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            ),
            'Category' => array(
                'className' => 'Category',
                'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            ),
            'Product' => array(
                'className' => 'Product',
                'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            ),
            'Subproduct' => array(
                'className' => 'Subproduct',
                'foreignKey' => 'subproduct_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            ),
            'Option' => array(
                'className' => 'Option',
                'foreignKey' => 'option_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            )
        );
```

ARTPROJECT MODEL:

```
public $hasMany = array(
          'Artdetail' => array(
              'className' => 'Artdetail',
              'foreignKey' => 'artproject_id'
          )  
        );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),

    );
```

Comment: Hmm somehow this looks a little bit weird.
Is it possible that the Artdetail has a different user than the Artproject?
If not, why does Artdetail have an User as well?
Every Artdetail is only able to have ONE Category, only ONE Product and only ONE Subproduct?
(By the way...i don't think that ArtDetail 'belongs to' a Product....doesn't it 'have one'?)
Is Subproduct a Product itself? What are your Options?
To be honest I did not really get what you are actually trying to achieve ;)
Looks to me like a little shop system.
If that is the case then you should maybe look for a different schema.